# Summation notation with matrix/vector (and Bernoulli numbers)

Tags: notation, bernoulli-numbers

I came across a notation that was unfamiliar ([Bernoulli Numbers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X0800054X)) that I reproduce below

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{n} \left(\begin{array}{cl} n+1\\ j\\ \end{array}\right) B_j = 0 \hspace{1cm} with \hspace{1cm} B_0 = 1$$

I'm not sure how to approach this notation, nor how to use it to produce the Bernoulli numbers. Also, as more of a bonus, the authors of the source say that the formula can be reproduced from

$$ \frac{x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n\frac{x^n}{n!} \hspace{1cm} |x|<2\pi $$

"by multiplying both sides by $e^x−1$, using the Cauchy product with the Maclaurin series for $e^x−1$, and then equating the coefficients of the powers of $x$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given identity allows you to compute the [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) $B_n$ for $n\geq 1$ recursively. Note that $\binom{n+1}{j}$ is not a vector, it is an integer number called [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

By isolating the last term of the sum we get the formula:
$$B_n=-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+1}{j}B_j.$$
For example, since $B_0=1$, it follows that 
$$\begin{align}
B_1&=-\frac{1}{1+1}\sum_{j=0}^{1-1}\binom{1+1}{j}B_j=-\frac{B_0}{2}=-\frac{1}{2},\\
B_2&=-\frac{1}{2+1}\sum_{j=0}^{2-1}\binom{2+1}{j}B_j=-\frac{B_0}{3}-\frac{3B_1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}.
\end{align}$$
Are you able to compute $B_3$?

As regards a proof of exponential generating functions of the Bernoulli numbers, you may take a look [HERE](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/proof-of-the-recursive-identity-for-the-bernoulli-numbers/).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I forgot about that notation for nCk. Thank you.